# From a scientific point of view, is it possible to be a vegetarian and keep joints in a healthy state?

Tags: nutrition, pain, vegetarianism, joints

I'm a vegetarian (not vegan, due to the fact that I eat dairy products and eggs). But for last two years, I have felt some discomfort and pain in my joints. I haven't been diagnosed yet (I'm going through medical screening now), but X-ray examination has already shown that my joints are not in a good state. I don't think that the vegetarianism is the main cause of my problems because I remember that sometimes I had felt discomfort in joints before I've become a vegetarian. But I really want to know scientific opinion about effects on my health from a vegetarian diet (especially on my joints) and is it vital for good health (especially for healthy joints) to eat meat, fish, jelly (gelatin)?

Comment: On nutrition: is omega 3 (fish oil) considered non-vegetarian by yourself?

Comment: Flax seed oil also contains omega 3.